# How to use two hr_timer in a linux module?

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi3

I am new to Linux kernel development. i have an application where I have to use two separate hr_timers. ( say one with 500us and other with 1 ms) : but when I try to configure and run the module, the system ( i am running in rpi3 ), the system is crashing after getting some output ( Just some printk("") in the respective callbacks).

How exactly the timers are running..? Do we need to exclude or lock something ? If someone can provide with a snippet of code will be helpful...
Thanks

Already tried configuring one hr_timer and it's working perfectly. But with two hr_timers, it's crashing...

Comment: If you could provide a snippet of code showing what you are doing currently, preferably a MVCE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), people for sure have an easier time helping you figuring out why your application is crashing.

Comment: Make sure you are using the `container_of()` macro with the correct parameters in each of your "timer expired" functions.